# How to LINQ Query Code First generated EF6 hierarchical entities (entities within entities)?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

*[images & code taken from another thread dealing with XAML & Treeview data [here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263256/hierarchical-code-first-ef-binding-to-wpf-treeview-impossible/22269198)*

Experts,

**Summary**

I create a 2 or more tiered object with EF & Code First, and the database creates all the Foreign Keys & fills them in wonderfully. But because I can't see those keys in code, I can't find a way to create LINQ queries that return the parent, it's child, that child, etc.

---

**Easy Structure**

**Access_Group -> Access_List -> Object_Group -> ...** (but just 2 levels are required for examples/proofs)

First, here is the *top* level class used to create the highest 'parent' items:

```
Public Class Access_Group
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of Access_Group)
    Implements IAccess_Group

    <Key>
    Public Property Access_GroupID As Integer Implements IAccess_Group.Access_GroupID
    Public Property Name As String Implements IAccess_Group.Name
    Public Property LastUpdated As Date Implements IAccess_Group.LastUpdated
    Public Property Active As Boolean Implements IAccess_Group.Active
    '------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Access_Lists As ObservableCollection(Of Access_List) Implements IAccess_Group.Access_Lists
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Access_Lists = New ObservableCollection(Of Access_List)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I create a child/children with the ObservableCollection... When I do this and *Add-Migration Foo*, EF6 in VS2012 creates what you would expect:

[image]

...and in the explorer:

[image]

...and in typical, acceptable EF style, the foreign key column is automatically created in MSSQL2012 as:

[image]

Great!

Now the above I did not create manually-the relationships, that is... I did it like this:

```
Private Sub AddData()
    Try
        ctx = New entitiesContext
        Dim d As Date = Now
        '--------------------------------
        Dim al As New Access_List
        ' lower classes not needed to be shown...
        With al
            .Active = True
            .Checked = True
            .LastUpdated = d
            .Name = "some access-list at " & d.ToLongTimeString
        End With
        '--------------------------------
        Dim ag As Access_Group = New Access_Group
        With ag
            .Access_Lists.Add(al)
            .Active = True
            .LastUpdated = d
            .Name = "some access-group at " & d.ToLongTimeString
        End With
        '
        ctx.Access_Groups.Add(ag)
        '
        Dim i As Integer = ctx.SaveChanges()
        Console.WriteLine("Seed complete! -> " & i)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim exText As String = "Seed Failed "
        Console.WriteLine(exText & "(Message): " & ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(exText & "(ToString): " & ex.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(exText & "(StackTrace): " & ex.StackTrace)
        Console.WriteLine("EntityValidationErrors: ")
        For Each eve As System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult In ctx.GetValidationErrors()
            Console.WriteLine("eve: OK? " & eve.IsValid & " - " & eve.Entry.ToString)
            For Each devr As System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError In eve.ValidationErrors
                Console.WriteLine("devr invalid property: " & devr.PropertyName)
                Console.WriteLine("devr error message : " & devr.ErrorMessage)
            Next
        Next
    End Try
End Sub
```

So you see, I use (for the top level):

ctx.Access_Groups.Add(ag)

...to add the Access_Group class, but only after it has had the Access_List class(es) associated/related to it added as:

```
With ag
    .Access_Lists.Add(al)
```

...and of course, our Access_List class has it's own children, as Object_Groups added before that as:

```
With al
    .Object_Groups.Add(og)
```

...and so on. So basically, each child id added to the parent, and finally the top level parent is added via our DBContext.

---

**The Problem/Proof**

When a LINQ query like this is done:

```
Dim ags = From ag In ctx.Access_Groups Select ag
```

I fully expected to get not just the top level classes, but if I dug into each, I would also get their children, grandchildren, etc.

*This is not so!*

A simple proof/debug Sub liek the below:

```
Public Sub PrintDebug(TheList As IEnumerable(Of Access_Group))
    For Each ag As Access_Group In TheList
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================")
        Console.WriteLine("ag: " & ag.Name & " has " & ag.Access_Lists.Count & " Access_List entries")
        For Each al As Access_List In ag.Access_Lists
            Console.WriteLine("ag -> al: " & al.Name & " has " & al.Object_Groups.Count & " Object_Group entries")
            For Each og As Object_Group In al.Object_Groups
                Console.WriteLine("ag -> al -> og: " & og.Name & " has " & og.Network_Objects.Count & " Network_Object entries")
                '...
            Next
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================")
    Next
End Sub
```

...yields what I consider (stupidly/ignorantly) to be a surprise:

```
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:00:49 PM has 0 Access_List entries
=======================================
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:08:56 PM has 0 Access_List entries
=======================================
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:09:14 PM has 0 Access_List entries
=======================================
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:12:31 PM has 0 Access_List entries
=======================================
[...]
```

WTF?

In POCOs, you get the whole class-including any children of that instance. But in EF (the way I'm doing it) the coupling is a lot looser.

---

**Need**

Somehow, I need to do a LINQ query for those top level items in the DB, and *automagically* have all the children in the DB that are associated with it be with it.

But because the FKs are not visible from code/business logic, I can't simply do a test for equality between keys...

How to smarter people than me do a LINQ query on hierarchical relationships like these & get all the goodies?

---

**Don't Wants**

- To resort to clunky DataSets and DataTables (been there, done that,
  may as well throw EF away at that point)...
- Direct SQL queries (negates EF and Linq efficiencies like lazy loading...
- Somehow having to hack the MS SQL tables manually to duplicate FK row data into
  'visible' columns (yuk)...

The most elegant way is usually the best...

What are your thoughts?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Experts,

Through persistence, perseverance, and blind luck, I think I found the issue-or at least a reason...

Short Version: I have to look up why, but in CF EF6 I unintentionally didn't enable "*Foreign Key Columns In The Model*", as in:

[image]

**BUT**... I used *Code First*, and not *Database First*... I'm just including the image above so you can understand the aspect I'm talking about. :)

Given the PrintDebug() sub above, the following query:

```
Dim agList As List(Of Access_Group) = _
    (From ag In ctx.Access_Groups.Include("Access_Lists") Select ag).ToList
Me.AccessGroups = New ObservableCollection(Of Access_Group)(agList)
Me.PrintDebug(Me.AccessGroups)
```

...yields the following result (compare to above/OP):

```
[...]
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:00:49 PM has 1 Access_List entries
ag -> al: some access-list at 5:00:49 PM has 0 Object_Group entries
=======================================
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:08:56 PM has 1 Access_List entries
ag -> al: some access-list at 5:08:56 PM has 0 Object_Group entries
=======================================
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:09:14 PM has 1 Access_List entries
ag -> al: some access-list at 5:09:14 PM has 0 Object_Group entries
=======================================
=======================================
ag: some access-group at 5:12:31 PM has 1 Access_List entries
ag -> al: some access-list at 5:12:31 PM has 0 Object_Group entries
=======================================
[...]
```

So the operative difference in the query is:

```
ctx.Access_Groups.**Include**("Access_Lists") Select ag
```

...Now to consult at the altar of Lerman & Miller to find out how I could/should have done this in Code First when I created the classes (or if I'm lucky, how to Add-Migration/Update-Database and do it *in situ*!)

Any input still welcome!

Thanks for your consideration!

P.S. Stack lost my original account and I had to start over (after many years), so now I can't even edit, comment, or update my posts or comments... ugh... I'll try to update with the CF way to enable the FKs as columns... *if I can* :(

Comment: (I can't even mark my answer as answer until I wait 2 days...)